# Can't set blance_class parameter after selecting the response column

Tags: h2o

I am starting with H2O using a Form Web UI, I am trying to fit the model using Distributed Random Forest. When I select Distribuited Random Forest in the **Build Model Section** I can see the parameter: `balance_classes` under the section **ADVANCED**.

[image: balance_classes parameter configuration]

but once I select the *response_column* with my variable (INT). I don't see such parameter.

[image: after selecting the decision variable]

My decision variable as two values: `0`,`1`, and the value `1` is imbalanced (15%).

Am I doing something wrong?, Thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your response column from `int` to `enum` and then it should be recognized as a binary column for classification. If you have a binary column with type `int`, the algorithms will assume you're doing a regression problem.

To convert your response column to enum, select enum from the drop down menu during the parse step. (In the below example you could switch `ArrDelay` to `enum` instead of `Numeric` for example)
[image]

There is functionality in flow so that if the response column is a binary categorical column then the `balance_classes` parameter will appear, but if the response column is real/int the `balance_classes` button will disappear.